# Autocomplete not displaying when typing into textbox but values are showing in console

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, materialize

I have a textbox on which I performed autocomplete using material design autocomplete. Upon entering values, the AJAX call was successfully made and values were returned; however the results was not displayed in the textbox.

The image below show the data being returned.

[image]

JS Codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', 'input.autocomplete', function() {
    var inputText = $(this).val();
    //alert(inputText);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data:'country='+inputText,
      url: '../inc/tax/server.php',
      //dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
        var countryArray = response;
        var countryList = {};
        console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < countryArray.length; i++) {
          countryList[countryArray[i].name] = countryArray[i];
        }
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: countryList
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP codes:

```
    $keyword = strval($_GET['country']);
    $search_param = "%$keyword%";

    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE '$search_param'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $countryResult[] = $row["name"];
        }
        echo json_encode($countryResult);
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Are you getting back valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Try uncomment:

```
//dataType: "json",
```

And you always should send [MIME header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) in response in PHP:

```php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

This code add before first `echo` in code ([learn more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Is it `data` instead of `source`?
Try changing

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: countryList
});
```

to

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: countryList
});
```

It will worked as expected I have tested.